# How to add a new role?

Tags: spring

I have a user with admin and user roles, now I need to add ROLE_SUPPORT and restrict this role to only reading the list of users, how can I do this?

```
public class UserController {

@Autowired
UserService userService;

@RequestMapping(value = "getAll", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public List<User> getUsers() throws IOException {
    return userService.getUsers();
}

@PostMapping("save")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public void save(@RequestBody User user) {
    userService.save(user);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "delete", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void delete(@RequestBody User user) {
    userService.delete(user);
}



@RequestMapping(value = "getUser", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json;charset=UTF-8")
@ResponseBody
public User getUser(@RequestBody RequestDto requestDto) throws IOException {
    return userService.getUser(requestDto.getId());
}
```

I suppose a new method should be added to this controller, but I could be wrong

```
public class User extends BaseEntity<Integer> {


public enum Roles {
    ADMIN
}

private String firstName;
private String lastName;
@Column(name = "username")
private String username;
@Convert(converter = PurshasedProductConverter.class)
private List<PurshasedProduct> purshasedProducts;


private String email;
private String activationCode;

@Convert(converter = AttachmentConverter.class)
private Attachment userAvatar;
public Attachment getUserAvatar() {
    return userAvatar;
}

public void setUserAvatar(Attachment userAvatar) {
    this.userAvatar = userAvatar;
}


@JsonProperty(access = Access.WRITE_ONLY)
private String password;
@JsonProperty(access = Access.WRITE_ONLY)
private String temporaryPassword;

@Convert(converter = StringArrayConverter.class)
private String[] roles;

private Date lastPasswordReset;

private Date dateCreated;
private Date dateUpdated;
private Date validatyTime;
private Boolean active;

public User() {
    lastPasswordReset = dateCreated = dateUpdated = new Date();
    roles = new String[]{"USER"};
}
```

That is, when requesting with the support role, a list of users should be returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring-Security provides this support by just adding @PreAuthorize annotation

```
@RequestMapping(value = "getAll", method = RequestMethod.GET)
**@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_SUPPORT')")**
public List<User> getUsers() throws IOException {
    return userService.getUsers();
}
```

Comment: and if I make a request for a different role, do I have a problem?

Comment: that is, will this method work for a role such as ADMIN

Comment: You need to add all roles to which this API needs to be exposed.

Comment: and how does spring understand that the role which in hasrole is the value of the role field in the user?